# Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\chatsystem\index.php on line 63

Tags: php, jquery, chat, undefined

I get this error... Its a chat system iver been working on for a couple of days. And the lines are:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Velkommen, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="#">Forlad Chatten</a></p>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // jQuery Document
        $(document).ready(function(){
        //If user wants to end session
        $("#exit").click(function(){
        var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
        if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}      
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: just make sure you have `session_start()` on top of your php file.

Comment: i have that and it still doesnt work

Comment: @AutKix where did you set `$_SESSION['name']`?

Comment: @AutKix then just make sure in login, that name is being set.

Comment: The code is here:

if(isset($_POST['enter'])){
    if($_POST['name'] != ""){
        $_SESSION['name'] = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
    }
    else{
        echo '<span class="error">Please type in a name</span>';
    }
}

Comment: I can make a pastebin with the code

Comment: Its here: http://pastebin.com/G31MBBkd

Answer (score 0):

You have to start your session at the top of your file with:

```
session_start();
```

So you have access to the Session Array.

Also make sure you have set `$_SESSION['name']`!

You can check if `$_SESSION['name']` isset so you don't get a warning and it's only outputed when it is set like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['name'])) echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>
```

Comment: I do have the

session_start();

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put a die() after loginFrom() on line 28 like so:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
    loginForm();
    die();
}
```